# get the median in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics, median

i have a question, i was solving a problem of hackerank sql, the problem is the following:

> A median is defined as a number separating the higher half of a data set from the lower half. Query the median of the Northern Latitudes (LAT_N) from STATION and round your answer to 4 decimal places.

the input format is the following:

```
field, type
id, number
city, varchar
state, varchar
lat_n, number
long_w, number
```

i saw this solution, i'm so confused:

```
SELECT ROUND(S1.LAT_N, 4) 
FROM STATION AS S1 
WHERE (SELECT ROUND(COUNT(S1.ID)/2) - 1 
       FROM STATION) = 
      (SELECT COUNT(S2.ID) 
       FROM STATION AS S2 
       WHERE S2.LAT_N > S1.LAT_N);
```

my question, is it possible for s2.lat_n and s1.lat_n to be compared if they are literally the same column?

pd: i'm a sql begginer, i'm sorry if my english is bad, the english is not my native language

Comment: Your English is fine, better than some who have English as their first language :)

Comment: They're the same column in different rows.

Comment: yes, they can as @Barmer mentioned here you are comparing the column name but for different rows

Comment: how do you know that? sorry my sql knowledge is still quite low

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @countno int,@finalcount int
select @countno=count(LAT_N) from station

select @finalcount=(@countno+1)/2


SELECT CAST(LAT_N AS DECIMAL(10,4)) 
FROM   station
ORDER BY LAT_N
OFFSET @finalcount-1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```